# What is the difference between _ and _variable in prolog?

Tags: syntax, prolog

I have encountered a lot of problems with a literal that starts with a `_` such as `_Peter`. So what exactly would be the difference between:

`good(_,_).`

and

`good(_,_Peter).`

Thank you for answering my question!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`_` alone is an anonymous variable. Multiple occurrences in the same clause (or the same read-term) represent different variables.

A variable starting with `_` but containing further characters is not an anonymous variable. Several occurrences represent the same variable.

By convention, many Prolog systems require that variables occurring only once need to start with a `_`. But this is a convention leading in most implementations to warnings only.